# Replacing Text In Buffered String

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing, buffer

I'm working on a program that modifies the output of mysqldump as it is produced, for which I currently have code that reads in the output of mysqldump in chunks a fixed number of bytes in size.  I need to be able to both do regular expression matches, as well as regex replaces on this text as it's read in (running the regexes on the final text output is not possible as the  final file size is many gigabytes).  I'm writing my code in PHP, though I believe the problem (and it's solution) ought to be language agnostic.

Right now a psuedocode of what I have looks like this:

```
$previous_chunk = "";
while (!end_of_file($reader)) {
    $chunk = $reader.read() //read in a few thousand characters from the file
    $double_chunk = $previous_chunk + $chunk;
    // do regular expressions on the double chunk (to catch matches that span the chunk boundary)
    $output_file.write($chunk);
    $previous_chunk = $chunk;
}
```

Which runs aground on two problems.  The first is that each chunk is being evaluated by the regular expressions twice, so if a match occurs in a chunk (and not spanning chunk boundaries) it will trigger that match twice even though the matching text only occurs once.  The second problem is that this still doesn't allow me to do replacements on the matches.  The regular expressions will replace the text in the `$double_chunk` but I only write `$chunk` to the output file, which is not affected by the replacement.

One thought I had was that I don't expect any of my regular expressions to need to span multiple lines (delimited by `\n` characters), so I could make a second buffer in my program, running the regexes only on completed lines, and then writing out to the target file line by line instead of chunk by chunk.  Unfortunately, due to the nature of the output from mysqldump, there are some extremely long lines (some are literally hundreds of megabytes) so I don't think this is a feasible option.

How can I, with some reasonably sized memory footprint (say a few dozen MB) read in this file and modify it in-stream with regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

```
$chunk = $reader.read() //read in exactly $chunk_length characters from the file (or less iff EOF reached)
while (!end_of_file($reader)) {
    $previous_chunk = $chunk;
    $chunk = $reader.read() //read in $chunk_length characters from the file (or less iff EOF reached)

    $double_chunk = $previous_chunk + $chunk;
    // do regular expressions on the double chunk (to catch matches that span the chunk boundary)
    $previous_chunk = substr($double_chunk, 0, $chunk_length);
    $chunk = substr($double_chunk, $chunk_length);
    $output_file.write($previous_chunk);
}

// do regular expressions on $chunk to process the last one (or the first and only one)
$output_file.write($chunk);
```

Problems 1 & 2 both solved by doing the regex replace, and then assigning the resulting string chunks back to $previous_chunk and $chunk, assuming that what you are using as a replacement string will not re-trigger a match. This changes the `write` to use $previous_chunk, so that $chunk is available to be changed on the next opportunity to catch a chunk-spanning match.

**Also**, *importantly*, the above assumes that the replacement is the same length as the string being replaced. If not, then the chunk size changes dynamically after the replace and the above solution is too naive to deal with it. If the replacement string is a different length, then you'll have to keep track of the changing chunk boundary somehow.

Comment: The replacement is not the same size as the matched string (essentially I'm replacing "foo" with "foobar") so this isn't going to do it for me I'm afraid.  Not a bad attempt though.